# Creating a random colour grid with all adjacent colours different

Tags: java

So I have the following problem set to me: Write a program that takes an integer command-line argument N, and uses two nested for loops to print an N-by-N board that alternates between 6 colours randomly separated by spaces. The colours are denoted by letters (like 'r' for RED, 'b' for BLUE). You are not allowed to have two of the same colour next to eachother.

So, I know I probably need arrays to get around this problem. I tried several methods that all came up wrong. The following is one of my recent attempts, but I am unsure as how to now go through the grid and correct it. What the code does is make every row randomized with no colour left or right the same, but the columns are not fixed.

Note that I am a first year CS student with no programming history. I am guessing the solution to this problem isnt too complex, however, I cant see a simple solution...

```
    int N = StdIn.readInt();
    int array1[] = new int[N];
    for (int column = 0; column < N; column++) {
        int x = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {

            int c = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);

            while (x == c) {
                c = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
                array1[row] = c;
            }
            if (c == 1) {
                System.out.print("R ");
            }
            if (c == 2) {
                System.out.print("O ");
            }
            if (c == 3) {
                System.out.print("Y ");
            }
            if (c == 4) {
                System.out.print("G ");
            }
            if (c == 5) {
                System.out.print("B ");
            }
            if (c == 6) {
                System.out.print("I ");
            }

            x = c;

        }

        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Comment: I just tested your code. Its working fine. I inputted 5 and I got 5x5 grid with all different colors you mentioned.

Comment: No adjacent colours are allowed to be the same.

Comment: Do you mean row wise or column wise? I dont see anything adjacent row wise at all, but I do see column wise.

Comment: Yes. Say I have a "R", printed somewhere in the grid. The letter to its left, right, top and bottom has to be different to itself. This goes for all the letters in the grid. No adjacent letter(colour) can be the same.

Comment: In that case make 2D array and feel those with your values and then check them whether your condition satisfy or not. If you found any adjacent duplicate then replace that. I think you will have to check only top and bottom elements only.

Comment: One more thing if you are going to replace duplicate element then make sure you are confirming that element is not duplicate to adjacent element.

Answer (score 1):

this was my solution for the problem. Quite convoluted though, but the logic behind it is straightforward. Each time you assign a new colour to your 2D array, you need only check the value of the array to the top and to the left of the position where you want to assign a new colour. You can only do this after you have assigned colours to the first row of the array however so you need to create separate conditions for the first row.

```
public class ColourGrid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        char[][] clrGrid = new char[N][N];
        char colours[] = {'r','b','y','w','o','g'} ;
        for (int counter = 0 ; counter < N; counter++) {
            for (int counter2 = 0 ; counter2 < N; counter2++) {
                if (counter == 0 && counter2 == 0) {
                    clrGrid[counter][counter2] = colours[(int)(Math.random()* 5 + 1)] ;
                }
                else if (counter != 0 && counter2 == 0) {
                    clrGrid[counter][counter2] = colours[(int)(Math.random()* 5 + 1)] ;
                    while (clrGrid[counter][counter2] == clrGrid[(counter)-1][counter2]) {
                        clrGrid[counter][counter2] = colours[(int)(Math.random()* 5 + 1)] ;
                    }
                }
                else if (counter == 0 && counter2 != 0) {
                    clrGrid[counter][counter2] = colours[(int)(Math.random()* 5 + 1)] ;
                    while (clrGrid[counter][counter2] == clrGrid[(counter)][counter2-1]) {
                        clrGrid[counter][counter2] = colours[(int)(Math.random()* 5 + 1)] ;
                    }
                }
                else if (counter != 0 && counter2 != 0) {
                    clrGrid[counter][counter2] = colours[(int)(Math.random()* 5 + 1)] ;
                    while (clrGrid[counter][counter2] == clrGrid[(counter)-1][counter2] || clrGrid[counter][counter2] == clrGrid[counter][(counter2)-1]) {
                        clrGrid[counter][counter2] = colours[(int)(Math.random()* 5 + 1)] ;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    clrGrid[counter][counter2] = colours[(int)(Math.random()* 5 + 1)] ;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int counter = 0 ; counter < N; counter++) {
            System.out.println("");
            for (int counter2 = 0 ; counter2 < N; counter2++) {
                System.out.print(clrGrid[counter][counter2] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```